# Automatic vectorization with g++ of a loop with bit operations

Tags: c++, g++, vectorization, simd

Is it possible to vectorize this loop (with g++)?

```
char x;
int k;
for(int s = 0; s < 4; s++) {
  A[k++] += B[x&3];
  x >>= 2;
}
```

`A` and `B` are pointers to non-overlapping float arrays; `B` has indices 0 to 3. I need to maximize portability as this is for an `R` package, so the best would be to rewrite in such a way that g++ would be able to vectorize it alone, as I don’t know how to make SSE code portable in this context (the package `RcppEigen` makes the library `Eigen` available so it is possible).

Many thanks in advance for your thoughts.

**P.S.** The code in which it is nested looks like

```
int k = 0;
for(size_t j = 0; j < J; j++) {
  char x = data[j];
  for(int s = 0; s < 4; s++) {
    A[k++] += B[x&3];
    x >>= 2;
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem like a very good candidate for SIMD vectorisation - is it really a performance bottleneck in your code ?

Comment: Yes, it is nested in another loop... the code performs satisfyingly but vectorizing this would be really great.

Comment: Can't you swap the two loops, i.e. make the `s` loop the outer, and another loop the inner, and then vectorize the now-inner loop?

Comment: Can you add the outer loop above too ? Is `k` the outer loop index ? Also, presumably when you say SIMD vectorization you mean x86 (i.e. SSE, AVX, etc), with intrinsics ?

Comment: The whole code is a bit lengthy but I'll post a simplified version.

Comment: I think swapping the two loops is potentially an interesting idea — I didn’t even consider it before. However I fear that  going through `A[]` four times will slow down the process due to increased memory access...

Comment: @Elvis: Please clarify requirements in regard to SIMD - is this x86 ? If so, are you limited to a particular SIMD instruction set (SSE ? AVX ? AVX2 ?) ? And presumably you want to implement this with intrinsics ?

Comment: "Gather" might be a keyword for the reads of B.

Comment: Well, I need some portability (this will be inside an R package). I would prefer to rewrite it in a way that g++ can vectorize it with `-O3`.`A[]` and `B[]` are float arrays.

Comment: @MarcGlisse: `B[]` only seems to have a 2 bit index (0..3) so it may be that a permute or similar can be used here.

Comment: @Elvis: OK - you really need to make this clear in the question then, since you don't want to explicitly vectorize the code. The question should really be more like "How to I make this code amenable to automatic vectorization by gcc ?".

Comment: @Elvis: what are the four values in `B[]` ? Are they "special", or related in any way, or just four arbitrary values ?

Comment: Nice question. They are related values: `B[0]` is arbitrary, `B[1] = B[0] + a`, `B[2] = B[0] + 2*a`, and `B[3] = 0` (`a` is arbitrary). Can you do something with this?!

Comment: Interesting snippet. I've tried to make it faster with precomputed LUTs and valarray-ops, but to no avail yet (on the contrary, it even lost performance on both g++-4.9 and clang-3.5). Tmwr I'll give even FORTRAN (95) a chance.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am very pleased by the attention this question received.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a solution with using of AVX2 :

```
__m256 _B = _mm256_setr_ps(B[0], B[1], B[2], B[3], B[0], B[1], B[2], B[3]);
__m256i _shift = _mm256_setr_epi32(0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14);
__m256i _mask = _mm256_set1_epi32(3);
for (size_t j = 0; j < J/2; j++)
{
    short x = ((short*)data)[j];
    __m256i _index = _mm256_and_si256(_mm256_srlv_epi32(_mm256_set1_epi32(x), _shift), _mask);
    _mm256_storeu_ps(A, _mm256_add_ps(_mm256_loadu_ps(A), _mm256_permutevar8x32_ps(_B, _index)));
    A += 8;
}
```

Comment: This is spectacular, unfortunately I won't be able to use it — yet. Maybe later, if I learn how to write portable code including this kind of thing.

Comment: Using is simple: #ifdef __AVX2__ <my code> #else <your code> #endif

Answer (score 3):

I found another way of optimization with using of SSSE3 instructions:

```
__m128i _B = _mm_castps_si128(_mm_loadu_ps(B));
__m128i _mul = _mm_setr_epi16(64, 64, 16, 16, 4, 4, 1, 1);
__m128i _and = _mm_set1_epi8(12);
__m128i _or = _mm_setr_epi8(0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3);
for (size_t j = 0; j < J; j++)
{
    const char x = data[j];
    __m128i x1 = _mm_set1_epi8(x);
    __m128i x2 = _mm_mullo_epi16(x1, _mul);
    __m128i x3 = _mm_srli_epi16(x2, 4);
    __m128i x4 = _mm_and_si128(x3, _and);
    __m128i x5 = _mm_or_si128(x4, _or);
    _mm_storeu_ps(A, _mm_add_ps(_mm_loadu_ps(A), _mm_castsi128_ps(_mm_shuffle_epi8(_B, x5))));
    A += 4;
}
```

But I think that previous variants are better.

Comment: All this is great. I save it for later -- I won't use code I can't check and understand! But I think I'll try to learn these instruction sets. Any good pointers?

Answer (score 2):

Without resorting to SIMD intrinsics I don't think there is a great deal you can do, but you may be able to at least encourage the compiler to vectorize the 4 additions per iteration:

```
int k = 0;
for(size_t j = 0; j < J; j++) {
  char x = data[j];
  float C[4] __attribute__ ((aligned(16)));
  for(int s = 0; s < 4; s++) {
    C[s] = B[x&3];
    x >>= 2;
  }
  for(int s = 0; s < 4; s++) {
    A[k + s] += C[s];           // this loop should be vectorized
  }
  k += 4;
}
```

Comment: I like this -- I’ll try it now. It seems likely to improve the result for a minimal amount of work.

Comment: I don't get it. g++ unrolls the loop and doesn't try to vectorize it.

Comment: Oh - that's disappointing - try gcc 5.2.1 if you're not on it already - also try clang 3.7.0, which seems to beat gcc in some benchmarks I've been running recently.

Comment: With -O2 -ftree-vectorize the loop is vectorized... but it's slower :(

Comment: It unrolls! I'll try something different though.

Comment: From what I found yet from  valarray-experiments `B[whatever]` is the bottleneck; **even if** it's just looked up from precomputed table.

Comment: I wrote an inline function for the loop to be vectorized and I used `__attribute__` to have it compiled without unrolling and tree-vectorize on: it worked, but it's still slower...

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how big your outer loop is it might be worthwhile to pre-compute a LUT for the sets of four constants which you are going to be adding in your inner loop:

```
const float C[256][4] = {
    { B[0], B[0], B[0], B[0] },
    { B[1], B[0], B[0], B[0] },
    { B[2], B[0], B[0], B[0] },
    { B[3], B[0], B[0], B[0] },
    { B[0], B[1], B[0], B[0] },
    { B[1], B[1], B[0], B[0] },
    { B[2], B[1], B[0], B[0] },
    { B[3], B[1], B[0], B[0] },
    ...
    { B[3], B[3], B[3], B[3] }
} __attribute__ ((aligned(16)));
```

(your probably want to generate this LUT programmatically, rather than coding it inline as above).

Then the actual processing could be simplified to:

```
int k = 0;
for(size_t j = 0; j < J; j++) {
  const uint8_t x = data[j];
  for(int s = 0; s < 4; s++) {
    A[k + s] += C[x][s];
  }
  k += 4;
}
```

which should vectorize completely, if your compiler is having a good day.

Obviously this is only worthwhile if `J` is sufficiently large that the cost of setting up the `C` LUT can be amortised over a large number of subsequent iterations.

Comment: I actually thought of that at some point of the development, and never tried it. I started only recently to check which loop where vectorized or weren't, and didn’t make the connexion. I think it's worth a shot, the outer loop is fairly big.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my already mentioned c++14 attempt to hack that faster, which yielded less than than zero to nothing; in fact `vectorized_op` is roughly 20% slower than `unvectorized_op` in the working, and 200% slower in the mocked version.

g++-4.9.2/clang++-3.5.0 on x86:64 Debian  Jessie
with

```
 -std=c++14 -O3 -Wall -pedantic -msse4.1 -ftree-vectorize -ffast-math
```

(resp += -stdlib=libc++ for clang)

**(updated)**

```
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <valarray>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <fstream>

using std::size_t;
using std::endl;
auto& Log = std::cout;

using real_type = float;
using ra_type = std::valarray<real_type>;
using ia_type = std::valarray<size_t>;
using workload_type = unsigned char;
using ca_type = std::valarray<workload_type>;

static constexpr bool BUILD_PIVOTS_H = false;
static constexpr size_t B_SIZE = 4;
static constexpr size_t MAX_CHAR = 256;
static constexpr size_t PRECOMPUTED_SIZE = MAX_CHAR * B_SIZE;
static std::array<workload_type, PRECOMPUTED_SIZE> PRECOMPUTED __attribute__ ((aligned(16)));
static std::array<real_type, PRECOMPUTED_SIZE> LUT __attribute__ ((aligned(16)));

struct sentry {
    sentry(const std::string& s) {
        Log << s << endl;
    }    
};


void unvectorized_op(ra_type& A, ra_type&B, const ca_type& data) {
    static sentry _("unvectorized_op:");
    int k = 0;
    for(size_t j = 0; j < data.size(); ++j) {
        char x = data[j];
#ifdef MOCK        
        for (auto& i : {0,1,2,3})
            A[k++] = real_type(0);
#else        
        for(int s = 0; s < 4; ++s) {
            A[k++] += B[x&3];
            x >>= 2;
        }
#endif        
    }
}    


void vectorized_op(ra_type& A, ra_type& B, const ca_type& data) {
    static sentry _("vectorized_op:");
    ra_type bflat(A.size());

    auto beg = std::begin(bflat);
    std::for_each(std::begin(data), std::end(data), 
        [&beg] (const workload_type& x) {
            const auto& it = &LUT[/*unsigned workload_type)*/(x)*4];
#ifdef MOCK            
            for (auto& i : {0,1,2,3})
                *(beg++) = real_type(0);
#else                       
            std::for_each(it, it + 4, 
                [&beg] (const real_type& c) {*beg = c; ++beg;}
            );
#endif                                   
        }
    );

    A = bflat;
}


int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int magnitude  = -1;

    if (argc > 1) {
        try {
            magnitude = std::stoi(argv[1]);
        } catch (const std::runtime_error& e ){
            /*ignore*/
        }       
    }

    if ((magnitude < 1) || (magnitude > 10)) {
       Log << "no magnitude between 2 and 8 given; choosing 5\n";  
       magnitude = 5;
    }

    /* precomputing the pivoting */ {
        size_t i = 0;
        workload_type x = 0; 

        std::generate(std::begin(PRECOMPUTED), std::end(PRECOMPUTED),
            [&i, &x] () {
                workload_type rv = x & 3;
                x >>= 2;                  
                ++i;
                (i % B_SIZE) == 0 ? x = i/B_SIZE : x >>= 2;
                return rv;
            }
        );
    }


    ra_type B(B_SIZE);

    ::srand48(::clock());
    std::generate(std::begin(B), std::end(B), ::drand48);
    std::transform(std::begin(PRECOMPUTED), std::end(PRECOMPUTED), 
                   std::begin(LUT),
                   [&B] (const workload_type& c) {
                       return B[c];
                   });


    for (auto &f : {unvectorized_op, vectorized_op}) {
        for (int i = 1; i < magnitude; ++i) {
            size_t workload_size = pow(10, i);
            size_t repetitions = pow(10, magnitude - i);

            ca_type data(workload_size);
            std::generate(std::begin(data), std::end(data), 
                    [] () {return workload_type(::drand48() * MAX_CHAR);});

            ra_type A(0., workload_size * B_SIZE);

            auto start = ::clock();
            for (unsigned long j = 0; j < repetitions; ++j) {
                A = 0.;
                f(A, B, data);
            }
            auto duration = ::clock() - start;

            Log << std::setw(8) << repetitions   << " repetitions with a "
                << std::setw(8) << workload_size << " workload took " 
                << double(duration)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC << "s" 
                << endl; 
        } // for i in magnitudes
    } // for auto f

    if (BUILD_PIVOTS_H) {
        try { 
            std::ofstream pivots_h("pivots.h");
            pivots_h << "#ifndef PIVOTS_H_ \n\n";
            pivots_h << "const char PIVOTS[256][4] = {\n";
            for (auto i = 0; i < 256; ++i) {
                pivots_h << "    {";
                for (auto j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
                    pivots_h << long(PRECOMPUTED[i*4+j]) << (j < 3 ? ", " : "");
                }
                pivots_h << ("}") << (i < 255 ? ",\n" : "\n");
            }
            pivots_h << "} __attribute__ ((aligned(16)));\n";
            pivots_h << "#endif\n" << std::endl;
        } catch (const std::runtime_error& e) {
            Log << "ERROR: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the Fortran 95 version:

```
module setup
    implicit none
    logical GENERATE_PIVOTS
    parameter(GENERATE_PIVOTS = .TRUE.)
    integer, parameter                        :: CHAR_TYPE = 1
    integer, parameter                        :: REAL_TYPE = 4
    integer(CHAR_TYPE), dimension(0:255, 0:3) :: PIVOTS 
    real   (REAL_TYPE), dimension(0:255, 0:3) :: LUT 
    real(REAL_TYPE), dimension(0:3)           :: B    

  contains

    subroutine init(B)
        implicit none
        real(REAL_TYPE), dimension(0:3), intent(in) :: B
        integer                                     :: r, c

        if (GENERATE_PIVOTS) then
            do r = lbound(PIVOTS,1),ubound(PIVOTS,1)
                do c = lbound(PIVOTS,2),ubound(PIVOTS,2)
                    PIVOTS(r,c) = int(iand(ishft(r, -c), 3), kind=1)
                end do
            end do
        else 
            !> @TODO load PIVOTS FROM file
        end if

        do r = 0,255
            do c = 0,3
                LUT = B(PIVOTS(r,c))
            end do
        end do
    end subroutine init

end module setup

module testling
    use setup 
    implicit none

  contains

    subroutine generate(A, data)
        real(REAL_TYPE), dimension(:,:),  intent(inout):: A
        integer(CHAR_TYPE), dimension(:), intent(in)   :: data
        integer                                        :: i
        !A  = LUT(data, :)
        forall (i=lbound(A,1):ubound(A,1))
            A(i,:) = LUT(data(i), :) 
        end forall
    end subroutine generate

end module testling

subroutine do_test(workload_size, repetitions)
    use setup
    use testling
    implicit none
    integer, intent(in)                               :: workload_size
    integer, intent(in)                               :: repetitions  
    real(REAL_TYPE), dimension(0:workload_size-1,0:3) :: A    
    integer(CHAR_TYPE), dimension(0:workload_size-1)  :: data
    integer(8)                                        :: s, e, cr, cm
    integer(4)                                        :: i 
    real                                              :: random  

    make_workload : do i = lbound(data,1),ubound(data,1)
        call random_number(random)
        data(i) = int(floor(random * 256),kind=CHAR_TYPE)
    end do make_workload

    call system_clock(s, cr, cm)
        do i = 1,repetitions
            call generate(A, data)
        end do
    call system_clock(e, cr, cm)

    write(*,'(I8, " repetitions for a ",I8," workload took ",F12.10,"s")')&
        REPETITIONS, WORKLOAD_SIZE, real(e - s,kind = 8)/cr
end subroutine do_test


program main
    use setup
    implicit none
    integer(8)          :: c, cr, cm
    integer(4)          :: i, seed   
    character(len=100)  :: buffer
    integer(1)          :: magnitude = -1
    integer             :: workload_size
    integer             :: repetitions  

    if (iargc() > 0) then 
        call getarg(1, buffer)
        read(buffer,*) magnitude
    end if

    if ((magnitude < 2) .or. (magnitude > 10))  then 
        write(*,*) "no magnitude between 2 and 8 given; choosing 5"  
        magnitude = 5
    endif     

    call system_clock(c,cr,cm)
    seed = int(c/cr, kind=4)
    call random_seed(seed)

    fill_B: do i = lbound(B,1),ubound(B,1)
        call random_number(B(i))
    end do fill_B
    call init(B)

    do i=1,magnitude-1    
        workload_size = 10**i
        repetitions   = 10**(magnitude - i)
        call do_test(workload_size, repetitions)
    end do

end program main
```

gfortran-4.9 also called with

```
-O3 -Wall -pedantic -msse4.1 -ftree-vectorize -ffast-math
```

---

**Summary**

Run with random workloads between 10 and 10M.

The normalized runtime for the unvectorized C++ version and the Fortran version for workloads < 1M is slightly worse than its nominal `O(n)` with reference to the workload size, roughly doubles above 1M, but stays slightly worse than the nominal `O(n)` with reference the new base for a 10M workload  .

The Fortran solution is roughly 40-50% faster than the unvectorized C++ version.

The "vectorized"-labeled C++ function is a mild catastrophy at best; minimum 20% slower than the unvectorized version.